Movie about groups getting sessions with implants during flights and conferences
I am referring to a science fiction color movie in English that I saw at least three years ago. It was probably released after 2000.
From what I remember, people get enrolled in a scheme (from a biotech company?) in which they end up having to fly to attend some events like conferences. During the flights and the meetings, these people are being drugged and have helmets or implants installed on their head. People seem unaware that this is happenning to them. The story is about the main character figuring out how he is being used.
The memory of the people is definitely altered in this movie, but I did not find it by searching for keywords such as "memory loss" or "amnesia".

sounds interesting, hope you find out - would be interested in watching it.

Possible duplicate

just because the question asks about the same movie another question asked about, does not mean the question is a duplicate. This one has a very different angle than the 'duplicate' one mentioned. Searching on this description would not net the description used in the other question.

You may be talking about Cypher a 2002 SF movie by Vincenzo Natali starring Lucy Liu and Jeremy Northam.
Trailer :



Plot from wikipedia (contain spoilers) :

Morgan Sullivan (Northam), a recently unemployed accountant, is bored with his suburban life. Pressured by his wife to take a job with her father's company, he instead pursues a position in corporate espionage. Digicorp's Head of Security, Finster (Bennett), inducts Morgan and assigns him a new identity. As Jack Thursby, he is sent to conventions to secretly record presentations and transmit them to headquarters. Sullivan is soon haunted by recurring nightmares and neck pain. When he meets Rita Foster (Liu) from a competing corporation, his life starts to become complicated.
[...]
Morgan discovers that all the convention attendees are spies like him, all thinking themselves individual spies working for Digicorp. While they are drugged from the served drinks, plastic-clad scientists probe, inject and brainwash them. Individual headsets reinforce their new identities, preparing them to be used and then disposed of. Morgan manages to convince Digicorp that he believes his new identity. He is then recruited by Sunway Systems, a rival of Digicorp. Sunway's Head of Security, Callaway (Webber), encourages Morgan to act as a double agent, feeding corrupted data to Digicorp.

